# Getting Data from MYSQL DB

Tags: php, android, android-emulator, json

I'm facing problems when trying to get data from a MySQL Database in an Android application

The output is:

```
06-29 11:40:42.123: E/JSON(1426): {"tag":"getroute","success":1,"error":0,"products":[]}
```

I think the problem I’m facing is in my PHP file (this is the code of the tag):

```
if( . . . )
{
    . . .
}
else if ($tag == 'getroute')
{
    $endloc = $_POST['end'];
    $op = $db->getRoutes($endloc);

    if ($op) 
    {
        $response["products"] = array();

        while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($op))
        {
            $product = array();
            $product ["uname"] = $data["uname"];
            $product ["start"] = $data["start"];
            $product ["end"] = $data["end"];
            $product ["meet1"] = $data["meet1"];
            $product ["meet1time"] = $data["meet1time"];
            $product ["meet2"] = $data["meet2"];
            $product ["meet2time"] = $data["meet2time"];
            $product ["meet3"] = $data["meet3"];
            $product ["meet3time"] = $data["meet3time"];
            $product ["ismoke"] = $data["ismoke"];
            $product ["iwomen"] = $data["iwomen"];
            $product ["ctime"] = $data["ctime"];
            $product ["seats"] = $data["seats"];

            // push single product into final response array
            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;

        echo json_encode($response);

        // user stored successfully     
    } 
    else 
    {
        // user failed to store

        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Making Route";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

I don’t know where the problem is. I searched over the internet and I found some tutorials but they always give me this error.

Function getroute :

```
public function getRoutes($endlocation) 
{
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE end = '$endlocation'");

   return $result;
}
```

Comment: do you face errors in your Android code or in PHP code ?

Comment: I assume this is not a native app, what are you using to build the app e.g. phonegap (which does not support php)

Comment: @snuil No I don't Face any Errors

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the number of results with [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) before you begin your while.

Additionally, immediately after your while, try using `print_r($data)` to verify that there is stuff in your record.

It seems to me that you're just having issues with your data source.